# Difference between on('click') vs on('tapone')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgestures

Building a site with jQuery and jGestures and have noticed some devices such as iPads won't respond to the on 'click' event instead they respond to 'tapone'.

I replaced all instances of 'click' with 'tapone' and after testing in various browsers I have noticed no issues. Browsers include the latest versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome for Windows and Safari on Ipad 4.

What are the drawbacks to replacing all instances of: on('click', .... with: on('tapone', ...
Will this cause issues with any desktop browsers?

Comment: It would seem that you could answer your own question by doing some testing yourself on various browsers.

Comment: I have tested in various browsers as I said and there seems to be no issues, but just because there seems to be no issues doesn't mean there aren't any. I would like to know if by replacing click with tapone is good practice or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` is the native browser event.

`tapone` is a custom event triggered by the jGestures library to capture a one-finger tap. (It also has `taptwo` etc for multi-touch taps.)

If you are using the library, use its events. Seems like it normalizes to `click` on non-touch browsers which is why you don't see any issues.

From the [documentation](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/documentation):

> On every native touchstart, touchend, gesturestart and gestureend-event, jgestures triggers a corresponding custom event (jGestures.touchstart,jGestures.touchend,jGestures.gesturestart and jGestures.gestureend) on the event-element.